# Functions of 2 variables and applications to economics

Tags: optimization, economics

Given the production function

> $Q := \sqrt K + L^2$,

determine the optimal level of production and the relative demand of the two inputs capital $K$ and work $L$.

The cost of a unit of capital is $r = 5$, the cost of a unit of work is $w = 60$, the unit price of the product is $p = 10$.

My book gives the following reference solution: optimal solution: $$K = 1, L = 3, Q = 10.$$

For what concerns the solution, I can say that the cost function is the following:

$$C = 5K + 60L.$$

For the rest, I do not know how to use the pricing information $p = 10$.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you for considering my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A profit maximising firm seeks to maximize the following objective
$$\max_{K,L}\{\Pi=p\cdot Q-TC\}$$
where $\Pi$,$pQ$ and $TC$ are the profits, revenue and the total cost respectively. Note that $TC=rK+wL$.
Subsitute $Q=\sqrt{K}+L^2$ and rewrite the obejctive function as 
$$\max_{K,L}\{\Pi=p\cdot (\sqrt{K}+L^2)-(rK+wL)\}$$
First order conditions wrt $K$ and $L$ are respectively
$$\frac{\partial{\Pi}}{\partial{K}}=\frac{p}{2\sqrt{K}}-r=0$$
and $$\frac{\partial{\Pi}}{\partial{L}}=2pL-w=0$$
These two equations will yield the optimal values for capital and labour as
$$K=(\frac{p}{2r})^2=(\frac{10}{2\cdot 5})^2=1$$
and 
$$L=\frac{w}{2p}=\frac{60}{2\cdot 10}=3$$
And you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are great! ;-)